# X-ray spectra: the strength of the lines?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, x-rays

**The Question**

In a typical x-ray spectrum the $\alpha$-lines are typically strongest. Is there an easy way of seeing why this is? and are their any notable exceptions?

**My Guess**

As a guess I would say that it was due to a greater overlap between two states of similar quantum number. But this is only a guess and may not be true for different values of $l$.

Comment: It is how the nomenclature works: the most intense line (of a group) was given the assignment alpha.

Comment: @Pieter oh really? I thought the alpha line was the one due to a transition from the $n+1$th level to the $n$th level. If you are correct then I guess my question is why is this transition most often the alpha transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the Siegbahn notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegbahn_notation

There is not much physics behind it. The nomenclature is essentially phenomenological: alpha is the strongest peak in a group, beta second strongest, etcetera.

Your guess is right for K$\alpha$ and K$\beta$: transitions to the $1s$ shell from the $2p$ and the $3p$ levels respectively. A large difference in overlap of the radial wave functions.

But L$\alpha$ and L$\beta$ are different. Those are transitions from the $3d$ levels to the spin-orbit split $2p$ levels. The intensities differ less than the K emission lines. It is caused by selection rules and multiplicities. And by life-time effects due to Coster-Kronig transitions (fast Auger transitions within the same subshell).